# Download json data into Pandas df?

Tags: python, html, json, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to download the json data from: [link](http://emweb.securities.eastmoney.com/ProfitForecast/ProfitForecastAjax?code=SZ00243).

The json data are divided into categories like:"pjtj:", "jgyc:", "mgsy:"...etc.

My codes returned :

> ValueError: arrays must all be same length

How to only extract the data under the "mgsy:" category?

My code:

```
url = "http://emweb.securities.eastmoney.com/ProfitForecast/ProfitForecastAjax?code=SZ002439"
df = pd.read_json(url)  
print(df)
```

Comment: looking at the length of each category may help with analysis:  print(len(j_obj['pjtj']), len(j_obj['jgyc']), len(j_obj['mgsy']), len(j_obj['yctj']), len(j_obj['jzcsyl']), len(j_obj['gsjlr']), len(j_obj['yysr']),len(j_obj['ycmx']))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use `requests` and `json` to download and extract the `json` data, and then convert it to a `pandas` `DataFrame` afterwards:

```
import requests
import json
r = requests.get("http://emweb.securities.eastmoney.com/ProfitForecast/ProfitForecastAjax?code=SZ002439")
d = json.loads(r.text)
df = pd.DataFrame(d["mgsy"])
print(df)
>>>   ratio value   year
0  25.91  0.63  2018A
1  25.69  0.80  2019E
2  26.26  1.01  2020E
3  25.65  1.27  2021E
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a intermediate step with json, here's an example:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

x = {
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "city": "New York"
}

y = json.dumps(x)
a = pd.read_json(y, orient = 'index')
```

This will return a dataframe with the information of the json. Hope it can help you